# Find shape of numpy array with differing column lengths

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What I want is to find the length of every column in a `2D` `NumPy` array.

If all the columns have the same length, this is trivial with `numpy.shape`. Nevertheless, if the columns have different lengths, `numpy.shape` doesn't actually tell me the lengths of the different columns.

```
a=np.asarray([[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]])
b=np.asarray([[0,1],[0,1,2],[0]])
a.shape,b.shape
((3,2), (3,))
```

I can get what I want fairly simply by doing something like,

```
lenb=[len(B) for B in b]
[2, 3, 1]
```

However, I feel like there must be a cleaner and quicker way to do it with `NumPy`?

Comment: Cleaner : `map(len,b)`?

Comment: First, those are rows. Second, you should pretty much never try to create a jagged NumPy array like that. NumPy isn't designed for it, indexing will break, broadcasting will break, everything and the kitchen sink will break... if you really need to use a jagged data structure, don't make it an array.

Answer (score 4):

Your `b` is an object array - 1d with list elements.  Most actions on that array will require a list comprehension or map.

```
array([[0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0]], dtype=object)
```

That 'object' dtype divides the array operations from the list ones. `shape` is an array property.  `len()` is the closest list function, but it has to be applied to each element separately.

In Py3, I much prefer the clarity of a list comprehension to map, but that's just a preference.  Functionally it's the same thing:

```
In [30]: [len(i) for i in b]
Out[30]: [2, 3, 1]
In [31]: list(map(len,b))
Out[31]: [2, 3, 1]
```

There is another possibility:

```
In [32]: np.frompyfunc(len,1,1)(b)
Out[32]: array([2, 3, 1], dtype=object)
```

---

You could change the elements of `b` to other objects with a `len`

```
In [39]: b[0]='abcd'    # string
In [43]: b[2]={1,2,1,3,4}   # set
In [44]: b
Out[44]: array(['abcd', [0, 1, 2], {1, 2, 3, 4}], dtype=object)
In [45]: [len(i) for i in b]
Out[45]: [4, 3, 4]
```

This should highlight the fact that `len` is a property of the elements, not the array or its 'columns' (which it doesn't have).